# How to run tslint only on modified files

Tags: javascript, npm, tslint

I want to configure tslint to run only on git modified files.
In packages.json I have the 'lint' task defined as:

```
{
  "scripts": {
     "lint": "tslint \"./src/**/*.{ts,tsx}\"",
     ...
  },
  "dependencies": {
     "tslint": "4.3.1",
     ... 
  },
  ...
}
```

So `lint` task works fine but it processes all files in project by hardcoded mask. Suppose I have a javascript `listModified.js` which produces list of git modified files. How do I pass the string produced by js as argument to tslint?

I can't use piping here since tslint accepts argument not a pipe. I failed to use eval to form argument.

How to do it?

Answer (score 2):

try xargs

```
echo "file1.ts\nfile2.ts" | xargs tslint
```

Obviously you can also use **git status** or **git log** to produce list of files to check

If xargs is not available in your system then try to use regular javascript API
https://www.npmjs.com/package/tslint#library-1

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i doesn't work at my configuration. xargs is suitable for *nix system. Is there any common npm solution or I have to introduce several platform-specific commands for each system?

Comment: Try to use tslint programatically then https://www.npmjs.com/package/tslint#library-1

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use some build system because it should have plugins that allow to check if file was modified by computing hash or by checking last modified time.

For example, using [gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) with [gulp-tslint](https://github.com/panuhorsmalahti/gulp-tslint) and [gulp-changed-in-place](https://github.com/alexgorbatchev/gulp-changed-in-place) plugins, and [jsonfile](https://github.com/jprichardson/node-jsonfile) package for reading and writing JSON files:

```
var changedInPlace = require('gulp-changed-in-place'),
    gulpTsLint = require('gulp-tslint'),
    jsonfile = require('jsonfile');

var tsHashFile = 'ts.hash.json';
gulp.task('tslint', function (cb) {
    jsonfile.readFile(tsHashFile, function (err, obj) {
        var firstPass = false;
        if (err) {
            firstPass = true;
            obj = {};
        }
        return gulp.src(tsGlob)
            .pipe(changedInPlace({
                cache: obj,
                firstPass: firstPass
            }))
            .pipe(gulpTsLint())
            .pipe(gulpTsLint.report())
            .on('end', function (event) {
                jsonfile.writeFile(tsHashFile, obj, function () {
                    cb(event);
                });
            });
    });
});
```

`tsHashFile` is used to persist computed hashes and when you will run `gulp tslint` again `tslint` will not be executed for files which hash is not changed.